# No matching lock-token

Tags: svn

According to the [Subversion documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.locking.html):

> after the commit is finished, svn
>   status shows that the lock token is no
>   longer present in the working copy.
>   This is the standard behavior of svn
>   commit—it searches the working copy
>   (or list of targets, if you provide
>   such a list) for local modifications
>   and sends all the lock tokens it
>   encounters during this walk to the
>   server as part of the commit
>   transaction. After the commit
>   completes successfully, all of the
>   repository locks that were mentioned
>   are released—even on files that
>   weren't committed. This is meant to
>   discourage users from being sloppy
>   about locking or from holding locks
>   for too long.

In trying to ensure this functionality works, I continually get this message when trying to commit a file change that has a lock in my working copy:

`svn: Cannot verify lock on path '/test/test'; no matching lock-token available`

Now, I've tested this scenario in two different working copies on Windows, and once on RHEL, and each time got the same error with a fresh checkout and no prior locks on the file.  If I unlock the file and then commit, no problem, commits happens.  If I use the svn:needs-lock property, same error if try to commit before unlocking the file.

I'm pretty sure the error is not occurring on the client side, but on the server side.  I thought it could be that the clients are not passing the local authorization token back to the Subversion server.  However, I've tried this with three different clients (2 CLI, and Subclipse).  Because it fails with three different clients, I'm feeling that the clients are passing the local authorization tokens back to the server.  So I'm pretty sure the server is the place I need to solve this, but where?

Comment: just to clarify , `svn lock test/test ; echo "foo" >> test/test ; svn ci -m 'check-in while holding lock' test/test` fails?

Comment: On both Unix and Windows (with some modifications for the platform), that command fails with 'svn: Cannot verify lock on path '/test/test'; no matching lock-token available' on both systems.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem:

```
svn: E160037: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160037: Cannot verify lock on path '/QHG3/trunk/kernel/Activator.cpp'; no matching lock-token available
```

i was able to fix this by "stealing" the lock:

```
svn lock --force AltMoverPop.cpp
```

Comment: What version of Subversion are you all using?  I believe at the time of this posting, I was using Subversion 1.6.x if that helps.

Comment: Working with a remote team and was having this issue. Stealing the lock worked for me.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, doesn't require a client but is just a simple command!

Answer (score 3):

Ohh Man.. I search post to pillar.
For me issue was same "Not working lock, "

Right click--> Get locks --> check "Steal lock".
Modified the file, and checked in.
Did it for me, for time being

Answer (score 2):

Well I did a little looking around with your question and found
[this](http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=720).

What it says to do is check if the files are read only, if they are, SVN thinks that the files are locked and no matching lock token will ever be available (since it's not actually locked).
So, if they are read only, try setting them to be writable.

If that doesn't work, take a look [here](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=61752).

Comment: Thanks, I found the same links in my own research on this issue. Sorry, the files are not set to read-only when the commit occurs and the working copies haven't been destroyed and recreated while a lock existed.  I'm betting the issue isn't on the client side as the two links you provided suggest, but rather on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the repository on the server got corrupted. Use `svnadmin` on the server to dump the repository, load it on a different machine in a temp repository and try the same operation with the temp repository.

If that fixes the error, backup the old repository and replace it with the temp repo.

Comment: I've done that check by using svnadmin verify, which is basically a svnadmin dump without the output.  The repository is sound.  We also have multiple repos, and we get the same behavior on all of them. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check disk space on the server? How about file permissions? And I still suggest to load the repo on a different machine (you can do that on your client). If that works, you'll know one bit more.

Comment: Disk space is okay.  File permissions, questionable, as I did not set up this server and those who did, really didn't know Subversion.  I'm fixing a lot of little stuff, so permissions could be a possibility, but won't be able verify that as the server is fairly locked down.  I don't have chown permissions, basically.  I would load the repo on another machine and test it, but they don't have a resource large enough to try that, let alone enough disc space for a complete dump without adding additional resources, which isn't going to happen for while.

Comment: In that case, get the source code for Subversion and search it for the error message. That might give you a clue which condition triggers the error.